# Equivalence Graphs

Tags: network-flow, network, symmetry

On the basis of this definition:

Two graphs are equivalent if they have the same set of edges (ex. (A,B),(A,C)) how would you determine equivalence for graphs that are not labelled:

ex.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a good definition:

> Two graphs are *equivalent* if they have the same set of edges (ex. (A,B),(A,C)).

It should be:

> Two graphs are *equal* if they have the same vertex set and the same set of edges.

E.g. these two graphs are equal:

[image: Example of two equal graphs]

(although they are *drawn* differently) and no two of these three graphs are equal:

[image: Example of three non-equal graphs]

Equivalence (typically called *isomorphism*) should be:

> Two graphs are *equivalent* if their vertices can be relabeled to make them equal.

E.g. these two graphs are equivalent:

[image: Two equivalent graphs]

(we replace the label $8$ by $4$ and the label $5$ by $3$).

These two graphs are also equivalent:

[image: Two equivalent graphs]

(in fact, they are the same two graphs in the previous example, but the second is drawn differently).

So, to answer the question *how would you determine equivalence for graphs that are not labelled*, we assign labels to the vertices of the graphs in such a way to make them equal.  In general, it's a non-trivial problem to determine whether or not it is possible to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is how to solve the graph isomorphism problem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem

Which is a curious but difficult problem at the moment. Of course, it is easy to see that, for example, graphs $J$ and $L$ in your example are equivalent, as are $K$ and $M$. The harder question is whether $L$ and $M$ are equivalent. For that, label the graphs like so:

[image]

Now, you want to relabel $a,b,\dots, g$ into $1,2,\dots, 7$ so that if two letters are connected, then the corresponding numbers are as well and vice versa. You can immediatelly see that $a$ and $1$ are the only two vertices with only one edge, meaning you must map $a$ to $1$. Next, since $(a,b)$ is an edge in $L$, and the only edge in $M$ containing $1$ is $(1,2)$, you must also map $b$ to $2$.

Next, you can see that $b$ has $2$ neighbors, one with degree $3$ and one with degree $4$, and the same is true for $2$ in $M$. This means you must map $c$ (the degree $3$ neighbor of $b$ in $L$) to $3$ (the degree $3$ neighbor of $2$ in $M$) and $d$ to $4$.

Now, $c$ has three neighbors in $L$, $b,d$ and $f$, so $3$ needs the same number of neighbors in $M$, meaning you must map $f$ to $5$, and then $g$ to $6$, leaving you to map $e$ to $7$, constructing the following mapping:
$$f(a)=1\\
f(b)=2\\
f(c) = 3\\
f(d) = 4\\
f(e) = 7\\
f(f) = 5\\
f(g) = 6$$

---

Notice that the following mapping was not really "chosen" by me, but rather it was the only relabling of the graph that *could* result in graph equivalence. If you prove that it indeed does (and it does), you have proven equivalence.

Comment: what specifically, because that is super broad - is there a formula etc?

Comment: thanks - this also helped alot!

Answer (score 1):

You can eithre show that some specific feature is present in one graph and not in the other; or explicitly construct an isomorphism (i.e. a bijection between the sets of verticves that is compatible with the edges). There is no general simple formula.

Fortunately, the four graphs depicted here have a few specific features (exactly one vertex of degree $1$, exactly one vertex of degree $4$) that allow to readily construct the desired isomorphisms.