# Algorithm to check if an equivalent node exists on a different graph with different labelings

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Let's say I have an undirected graph defined by a set of edges:

$$
\{(1, 2), (0, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3), (1, 2)\}
$$

This could be drawn as follows:

[image: graph]

Now, assume that I drew the same graph, but changed the numbers:

$$
\{(1, 2, 3), (0, 3), (0, 3), (0, 1)\}
$$

to form this:

[image: graph]

It's clear that these two graphs are identical, at least visually. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875758/equivalence-graphs) goes into more detail about this problem, but I'm looking for a solution to a more specific focus.

Now, we'll focus in on the node that is called $3$ in graph 1, and $1$ in graph 2.

This node is represented as $(1, 2)$ in the first graph, and $(0, 1)$ in the second. Now, here's my problem:

Suppose I am given a list of edges $b$, and one specific node $b_n$ from that list of edges. Also suppose I am given another list of edges $z$, which may or may not be equivalent in size. I now need to find out whether $z$ contains some node $z_n$ which, ignoring labelling, is equivalent to $b_n$.

By equivalent, I mean that if we only focus on the node $b_n$, its direct neighbours, and the edges connecting to the neighbours, it would be identical to that of $z_n$ *in the context of the given graph*, ignoring the numbering/labelling.

E.g:

Given $b=\{(1, 2), (0, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3), (1, 2)\}$, $n=3$ (0-indexed), and $z=\{(1, 2, 3), (0, 3), (0, 3), (0, 1)\}$. We can find that the result is true in this case, since there exists $n=1\Rightarrow z_n$ such that, removing all labels, $z_n$ is essentially equal to $b_n$.

In a more complex example, take this graph:

[image]

and this one:

[image]

Here, $b=\{(1, 2, 3), (3, 4), (0, 3), (0, 1, 2), (1)\}$, $n=4$ and $z=\{(4), (2, 3, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 0)\}$

We'd once again return true.

[image]

$b=\{(1, 2, 3), (0), (0, 3), (0, 2, 4, 5), (3, 5), (3, 4, 6), (5)\}$, $n=3$

[image]

$z=\{(1, 2, 3), (0, 7, 8), (0, 3), (0, 2, 4, 5), (3, 5), (3, 4, 6), (5, 9), (1, 8, 9), (1, 7, 9), (6, 7, 8)\}$

Once again, this is `true`, because if we only do a shallow check then the node's *direct* neighbours are the same nodes despite the different numbering, even if the secondary neighbours are different.

My question is: **Is there a generalised algorithm to check this, given the two graphs and an integer $n$? *If so, what is the most computationally efficient method?***

Comment: It sounds like you consider two vertices equivalent if their [neighbourhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(graph_theory)) are [isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism). So you still have to solve a graph isomorphism problem, but if the degree of the vertex is small then it might not be too expensive.

Comment: @Rahul thanks! I know virtually nothing about the subject, so I'm sorry if the question seems quite obvious/easy. I'll look into what you said!